# Rational Invariants of Algebraic Group Action

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a connected complex algebraic group acting on a variety $X$.  Write $\mathfrak{g}$ for the Lie algebra of $G$.  Then both $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ act on $\mathbb{C}(X)$, the ring of rational functions on $X$.

We clearly have an inclusion $\mathbb{C}(X)^{G}\subseteq\mathbb{C}(X)^{\mathfrak{g}}$, since $\mathfrak{g}$ is acting by infinitesimal translations.  My question is, do we also have the opposite inclusion, i.e. do we get $\mathbb{C}(X)^{G}=\mathbb{C}(X)^{\mathfrak{g}}$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is irreducible as a variety? Otherwise, consider the order two group $G=\{\pm I_2\}$ (the center of $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$) acting on $X={\mathbb C}^2$ in the natural fashion  (the generator of $G$ sends $(x,y)$ to $(-x, -y)$).

Comment: Yeah, I want to assume $G$ is connected, let me add that assumption. Thanks!